# How to get the array in object when press a certain button

Tags: vue.js

I am building a filter and the labels. When user press the first row, it will further provide more choices for user to search. I can show active button's choice(2nd row) successfully, but it can only get the first button "Stage Performance" choices. It seems have to update ActiveIndex to judge extract which button's choices. How can I change the activeIndex when user press the 1st row button?

Design:
[image: Design]

Template:

```
<swiper
  :slidesPerView="5"
  :navigation="true"
  :modules="modules"
  class="mySwiper"
>
 // Loop labels 
  <swiper-slide
    v-for="(label, index) in labels"
    :key="index"
    @click="handleActiveIndex(index)"
  >
    <button class="button-text">{{ label.type }}</button>
  </swiper-slide>
</swiper>
    
// Sub label
<div class="choice-list">
  <div
    class="choice"
    v-for="(choice, index) in labels[activeIndex].choice"
    :key="index"
  >
    {{ choice }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
setup() {
  /* Filter label */  
  const activeIndex = ref(0);
  const labels = ref([
    {
      type: "Stage Pefromnace",
      choices: [
        "All",
        "Music",
        "Chinese Opera",
        "Dance",
        "Theatre",
        "Multi-Arts",
        "Pop Concerts",
      ],
    },
    {
      type: "Festivals",
      choices: [
        "All",
        "International Arts Carnival",
        "New Vision Arts Festival",
        "New Vision Arts Festival",
        "Chinese Opera Festival",
        "Hong Kong Pop Culture Festival",
        "Other Festivals / Series Events",
      ],
    },
  // Other objects ... //
  ]);
  return {
    modules: [Pagination, Navigation],
    activeIndex,
    labels,
  };
}
```

Comment: And how is your `handleActiveIndex()` method implemented?

Comment: I tired define a function before just like below answer, and just activeIndex = index without value. However I add the missing .value back there are still something wrong. Could you talk about how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't defined the handleActiveIndex function.

```
const handleActiveIndex = (index) => {
  activeIndex.value = index;
};

return { 
  modules: [Pagination, Navigation],
  activeIndex, 
  labels, 
  handleActiveIndex, // return this function 
};
```

Comment: Theoretically, we just defined the function. It will set activeIndex as the which row1 button(index) and copy for showing row2 buttons later. However there are something wrong  and get "uncaught TypeError: _ctx.handleActiveIndex is not a function at onClick".

Comment: did you return handleActiveIndex fuction?

Added return code to answer.

Comment: You are right, I just made careless mistake and forget to return the value. It works now, thank you so much.

Comment: It's nice to hear that